# How to keep all the data from different Jframes in one object in java GUI

Tags: java, swing, object, user-interface

I am making a GUI and I have almost 10 frames each accepts data from user. I want to save this data in one object. I am wondering how to do that.like you make one object in main and access all the functions from there and store all the data in this one object.

Comment: please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't create multiple jframes. Reuse the same one. Create multiple `JPanel`. Use tabbed panels if you want all the screens at the same time.

Comment: Actually I have 2 classes one road(edges) and one city(vertex) and a Graph class that access both classes. I want to work with only Graph class object. All I want is that when i press submit button in different places all data should be stored in one object.

Comment: Google "model view controller pattern"

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

If the all data are "related to one object," you can make a class to represent this object; either

- make the class static, with all elements inside it
- or make the class a singleton

  ```
  public class ClassicSingleton {
      private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
      protected ClassicSingleton() {
          // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
      }
      public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
          if(instance == null) {
              instance = new ClassicSingleton();
          }
          return instance;
      }
  }
  ```